# annotation javascriptinterface not working

Tags: android, android-webview

```
    web = new WebView(this);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.htm");
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(new Logic(), "ob");
    setContentView(web);
```

---

```
    public class Logic {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void consol(String data) {
        Log.i("info", "* WebView : " + data);
     }
}
```

i read this : 
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object 
and  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html

logic is inner class, all the methods in logic are public, to all methods in logic i add @JavascriptInterface,
 i not using phonegap/proguard.

But in case of api 17+ the WebView can not access to the methods in logic (like consol).
i read here all the discussions in this topic and still not working.
Maybe it's something in the manifest file or project settings.

Any ideas ??

```
$(window).ready(
    function() {
        window.ob.consol("webview") // not working
        tmpitems = logic.getNews();
        var items = jQuery.parseJSON(tmpitems);
        logic.consol(" Start web");

        $("#rsslength").html(tmpitems.length());

        $.each(items, function(key, val) {
            // logic.consol(val);
            $("#rsslist").append(
                    "<li>" + val.channel + " : " + val.title + "</li>")
                    //logic.consol( val.category+"--" + val.date);
        });

    });
```

There are other files but what matters even this line does not work:

window.ob.consol("webview") // not working 
not print log.

Comment: please post source code for file:///android_asset/www/index.htm along with JS if any

Comment: I added in body of the question, the index file for some reason I can not post.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kothnhq7yegtzmf/AACvgIXwIh4XCOLVUVW9bzBKa?dl=0

Comment: did u tried moving line web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.htm"); after web.addJavascriptInterface(new Logic(), "ob"); ??

Comment: i did now, not help.
in devices below API-17 it's work fine.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? Still need help ....

Comment: I was having the same issue, and didn't even think to check my proguard setting until I read this ! Thank you!